# Use wget to grab entire tumblr?

Tags: css, http, recursion, wget, tumblr

I apologise in advance if this is against any rules, etc.
I'm attempting to locally clone my tumblr blog using wget, which works out great, minus one issue. It clones the page completely, but the theme I use has an infinite scroll script in it, so that until the user scrolls down to the last post, no other posts are loaded. This is an issue, as wget will only capture the first page, nothing further.

Currently, I'm using: *wget --random-wait -r -p -e robots=off -U mozilla http://.tumblr.com*

Is there any way I can accomplish this task using wget alone?
Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: Not a programming related question.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried starting off with `/archive`?

In any case, I found the following useful in getting a complete copy of a blog with a theme without an infinite scroll:

```
wget --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 XXX" \
--recursive --level=0 --convert-links --backup-converted --page-requisites \
--domains="xkcd.tumblr.com,media.tumblr.com" --exclude-domains="." --span-hosts \
http://xkcd.tumblr.com/
```

Answer (score 1):

`wget` won't do it because it does not process the javascript in the page. Your best bet would be to use the [tumblr API](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2). It provides a mechanism for grabbing and publishing blog data.

Comment: Almost thought as much. Thanks for the quick reply, Dave.
Looks like that's a task well above my experience though, which admittedly doesn't extend too far beyond a few months Python training.

Cheers.

Comment: It's surprisingly easy to use the most basic functions of the Tumblr API -- which is all you need to grab a blog's posts. All this requires is you signup for an API Key, and then you can make simple HTTP requests with the "public" portion of your API Key to paginate through a blog's posts.  Really, it's not so hard! Give it a try, maybe you'll learn something :)